# Is it possible to deliver an Android Instant App over a private LAN?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

My application incorporates peer 2 peer functionality so was wondering if there would be any restrictions stopping me including a basic http server that a new device could connect to in order to do an instant app install of the base, and p2p features without an available internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your private server can serve/download the files needed to the device, then...

First, a normal APK needs to be installed by either letting the user manually install it or with `adb install <apk>`.

Now, for an Instant App, you can't manually install it, you have to run:

`../Android/Sdk/extras/google/instantapps/ia run <instant-app>`

```
Usage: run [-s=<deviceSerial>] [-u=<url>] [<appArtifact>...]
Launches an instant app
      [<appArtifact>...]   Instant app ZIP, APK set, or list of APKs
  -s, --serial=<deviceSerial>
                           Device serial number
  -u, --url=<url>          Instant app URL
```

Question for you: can you do that?